# É possível remover o rolamento de um TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi

É possível remover o rolamento vertical e horizontal de um `TWebBrowser`?

Pesquisei em vários locais da internet, porém, não encontrei uma resposta válida, todos os exemplos eram falsos!

Comment: Posta seu código para o pessoal vê se pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Desabilitar é meio complicado, não tem uma propriedade para isso no componente!
Porem, posso te ajudar Ocultando as barras...

Adicione essas 2 linhas de código no OnDocumentComplete do TWebBrowser:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Body.Style.OverflowX := 'hidden';
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Body.Style.OverflowY := 'hidden';
```

Com isto, após carregamento da Página as barras são ocultadas!